# set hostname service docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I need to assign a hostname to a docker service in a docker swarm 1.12 cluster.

I have 3 nodes:

```
$ docker-machine ls
node-1    *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v1.12.1   
node-2    -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.101:2376           v1.12.1   
node-3    -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.102:2376           v1.12.1
```

5 services:

```
$ docker service ls
3a61zuut1moi  frontend  1/1       
3fi2rby9qvkr  nginx     1/1       
4k3uw95rjsbf  mongo     1/1       
a41hy01hj2qd  redis     1/1       
an02r7mfxerq  oauth     1/1
3oepkciv0wlh  rest      1/1
```

And 1 network:

```
$ docker network ls
8mvvwetvakh7        proxy               overlay             swarm
```

The services oauth & rest need to communicate between them throw domain name, oauth service is identified by oauth.example.com and rest service by rest.example.com.

- rest service ask to oauth service if user token already exist.
- oauth service have a JKS cert which allows connections through *.example.com

I need to assign oauth.example.com to oauth service, how can I do this?

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a late answer, but just in case you did not resolve it or someone is having the same issue. You can use aliases on the network.

```
services:
  oauth:
    networks:
      proxy:
        aliases:
         - oauth.example.com
  rest:
    networks:
      proxy:
        aliases:
         - rest.example.com
```

*From https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases*